# F# list.fold maximum

Tags: list, f#, max, fold

I wanted to use a new built-in function (list.fold) in F#. I have a list with numbers in it and I have to return the maximum of it. If the list is empty it should 0. I tryied to solve it this way:

```
let max a b : Nat = if a > b then a else b
let maxofList = List.fold max
let maximum (xs: Nat list): Nat = maxofList xs
```

I can't compile it and I don't know how to solve it in another way, maybe I just don't really understand how the built-in functions works. The input looks like this:

```
maximum [12N; 4N; 67N; 5N] = 67N
```

Comment: I can't compile it either; where did you find the type ``Nat``? Ignoring that, your third line (or alternatively your second line) is missing an initial value for the fold. If ``Nat`` is a type reflecting natural numbers (starting from 1), then ``1N`` would work.

Comment: I wanted to use Nat for the natural numbers but maybe my whole code is  just wrong. I wanted to try it in another way, with " match x with  " function, but I don't know how write it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, it is slightly confusing that you are using the `Nat` type - this is a custom type defined somewhere in a library that you are using, not a standard F# type. You should be able to get things to work with your `Nat` type, but I'll just simplify things and use an integer.

Now, your code is almost right. The only problem is that `List.fold` takes a function to combine the current state with the next element (that's your `max`) but it also needs an initial state. This should be a number that is smallest than anything else in your list. If you just have positive numbers, you can use zero:

```
let max a b : int = if a > b then a else b
let maxofList = List.fold max 0 // Added '0' as an extra parameter here!
let maximum (xs: int list): int = maxofList xs
```

In your case, this will likely be `0N`. Alternatively, you could use `List.reduce` which takes the first element of the list as an initial value and fails if the list is empty:

```
let maxofList = List.reduce max
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that there is also List.max (and List.maxBy): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.max%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D